In SurrealDB SQL, How do you find and update value in array of objects
Given the data below how do I write a SurrealDB SQL query that selects the record where the address array has an object with the key of 'door_no' and the value of '16' and update its postcode value to 'newpostcode'
[{
    firstname: “mike”,
    lastname: “qat”,
    address: [
        {door_no: 1, postcode:”ldksjd”},
        {door_no: 16, postcode:”ldsa”}
    ]
},
{
    firstname: “Lauren”,
    lastname: “zoop”,
    address: [
        {door_no: 326, postcode:”ldksjd”},
        {door_no: 22, postcode:”lond”}
    ]
}]


here's the answer
UPDATE table_name SET address[where door_no=16].postcode = "newpostcode";

